# Set Access table fields to a value when you do not know the field names

Tags: ms-access, field

I have a access table with several fields. I would like to read through all rows, all fields and if the field contains a NULL, set a default value of "". I am trying to read through the table using field definitions but am having trouble finding the existing value of the field.

```
Dim fld As DAO.Field  
Dim t As DAO.TableDef   
Dim fldVal as string (test variable to see if I can find value of field)  

    For Each t In cd.TableDefs 

  If t.Name = "PERSONS" Then   
    For Each fld In t.Fields
     Just trying to find the existing value here
      fldVal = fld.Value  


      If fld.Type = 10 And IsNull(fld) = True Then  
         fld.Value = ""  
      End If  

   Next  
 End If  
Next
```

Comment: Where is the problem?  Error message? If so, which line triggers it?

Comment: on line fldVal = fld.value I get an error: 3219 Invalid operation

Comment: If you `Dim fldVal As String` then you cannot assign a `Null` value to it. Try `Dim fldVal As Variant`.

Comment: I changed the def to variant and still it does not work. It works fine if I just try to get the field name using fldVal = fld.name.

Comment: Do I need to read the table in first? Maybe it is not showing the actual data value because I have not read in a record.

Comment: Thought so.. The below is working now:

Comment: Sorry about the messy code. I can never seem to edit it correctly on here.

Comment: strSQL = "Select * from PERSONS order by [IR Number], [last   name], [first name], [dob]"
    Set rs = cd.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If rs.EOF = True Then
'       message that PERSONS table is empty
      MsgBox ("The PERSONS table contains no records.")
    Else
      rs.MoveLast
      rs.MoveFirst
      For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount
       For iFlds = 0 To rs.Fields.Count
         
         fldVal = rs.Fields(iFlds).Value
       Next iFlds
      rs.MoveNext
      Next
    End If

Answer (score 1):

I think this may do what you want for the *PERSONS* table.

```vb
Dim cd As DAO.Database
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim t As DAO.TableDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim fldVal As Variant '(test variable to see if I can find value of field)

Set cd = CurrentDb
For Each t In cd.TableDefs
    If t.Name = "PERSONS" Then
        Set rs = cd.OpenRecordset(t.Name, dbOpenTable)
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            For Each fld In rs.Fields
                'Just trying to find the existing value here
                fldVal = fld.value

                If (fld.Type = dbText Or fld.Type = dbMemo) _
                        And IsNull(fld.value) = True Then
                   fld.value = ""
                End If
            Next fld
        rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
Next t
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
If fld.Type = 10 And IsNull(fld) = True Then
```

to

```
If fld.Type = 10 And IsNull(fld.Value) = True Then
```